# Create a two separate setup for AngularJS as frontend & PHP as backend

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

How can we create two separate setups, one for angular js & the other for PHP like MVC environment?

I want to build a web application with two folders: frontend & backend. 
From frontend AngularJS will hit the REST API of PHP and get the desired output.

Comment: Do you use WAMP(Windows Apache MySQL PHP)?

Comment: I use XAMPP alongwith PHP, MYSQL, Apache

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use WAMP, you can run the WAMP local server, which will let you use the serverside PHP in folder `C://wamp64/www`. WAMP can be accessed by going to `localhost` in your browser, which will give you access to tools such as phpMyAdmin, which comes with the WAMP installation. phpMyAdmin is an interface to allow you to interact with MySQL to create databases, edit databases, see databases, etc. Then if you want to run code like HTML with AngularJS, JavaScript and NodeJS, you can set up the Node app to run on `localhost:3000`. Although, you will need to add `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *')`
at the top of your PHP file if you want to allow communication between clientside AngularJS and serverside PHP.

Comment: I am actually looking for an working example.So that I can understand the whole working properly

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.